# How do I use encode_json with string in Perl?

Tags: json, string, perl, encode

Here is my code that I try to open the file to get data and change it to UTF-8, then read each line and store it in variable my $abstract_text and send it back in JSON structure.

```
my $fh;
if (!open($fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)',$path))
    {
    returnApplicationError("Cannot read abstract file: $path ($!)\nERRORCODE|111|\n");
    }
printJsonHeader;
my @lines = <$fh>;
my $abstract_text = '';
foreach my $line (@lines)
    {
    $abstract_text .= $line;
    }

my $json = encode_json($abstract_text);
close $fh;
print $json;
```

By using that code, I get this error;

hash- or arrayref expected (not a simple scalar, use allow_nonref to allow this)

error message also point out that the problem is in this line;
my $json = encode_json($abstract_text);

I want to send the data back as a string (which is in UTF-8). Please help.

Comment: @Zaid Your close vote is unwarranted: this one is not about usage per se but encoding stuff that isn't a reference.

Comment: @Zaid Much obliged.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you're using either [`JSON`](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.90/lib/JSON.pm) or [`JSON::XS`](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/JSON-XS-3.02/XS.pm).

Both allow for non-reference data, but not via the procedural `encode_json` routine.

You'll need to use the object-oriented approach:

```
use strict;   # obligatory
use warnings; # obligatory

use JSON::XS;

my $encoder = JSON::XS->new();

$encoder->allow_nonref();
print $encoder->encode('Hello, world.');
# => "Hello, world."
```